# How to post a value to custom column in admin order panel via Woocommerce API?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

**In Woocommerce, I have created a custom column to admin orders list page.**

```
<?php 

add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION' );
function MY_COLUMNS_FUNCTION( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = ( is_array( $columns ) ) ? $columns : array();
    unset( $new_columns[ 'order_actions' ] );

    $new_columns['MY_COLUMN_ID_1'] = 'MY_COLUMN_1_TITLE';

    $new_columns[ 'order_actions' ] = $columns[ 'order_actions' ];
    return $new_columns;
}
```

**Then, custom field for this column**

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION', 2 );
function MY_COLUMNS_VALUES_FUNCTION( $column ) {
    global $post;
    $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );



    if ( $column == 'MY_COLUMN_ID_1' ) {
        echo ( isset( $data[ 'MY_COLUMN_1_POST_META_ID' ] ) ? $data[ 'MY_COLUMN_1_POST_META_ID' ] : '' );
    }
}
```

**But I don't know how to post a string to the specific custom field via WooCommerce API?**

Comment: Can you clarify "specific custom field via WooCommerce API"?

Comment: Ok, here is what I want exactly. My API creates a shipment PDF with pdfkit by getting order's data from WC. After that, I need to push this pdf's url link to the Admin Orders Page where I can easily print it out from custom column that I've created before.

Comment: Sounds cool. How is your API saving the URL data to the order?

Comment: Saving it as a string in MongoDB for instance "http://myapi.com/pdf/files/xxx.pdf"

Comment: Is it saved in relation to the order? How does one retrieve the data normally? I don't know anything about your API so it's hard to suggest an answer.

Comment: Ah, I understand now what you ask. I have 2 DBs, one is mysql for WC and the other one is Mongo for my API. 2 different servers, 2 different dbs. Url link is located in mongo but need to post it to mysql(related order's table).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158279/discussion-between-aras-serdaroglu-and-helgatheviking).

Comment: I'm signing off for the night, but I think you will want to save the URL as meta for the order in WC when you create it. Then it would be very easy to retrieve. Or at the very least, save it in your Mongo DB with an "Order ID" key if you have an API for retrieving the data from your Mongo DB. Then when you need the URL you can make a call to your Mongo DB and search by the Order ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tweak Andrew's answer just a little to start using the order object more and rely less on post meta. I'm pretty sure WooCommerce will move at least it's core meta into a custom table eventually.

```
function wc_add_custom_order_column_content( $column ) {
    global $post, $the_order;

    if ( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->get_id() !== $post->ID ) {
        $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    }

    // Only continue if we have an order.
    if ( empty( $the_order ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( 'custom_column' === $column ) {
        // Use order class getters to retrieve what you need.
        echo $the_order->get_formatted_order_total();
        // Or, if it's not a core field, it may be in meta.
        // echo $the_order->get_meta('_some_meta_key');
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'wc_add_custom_order_column_content' );
```

Comment: Yes agreed that's a better method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to add a custom column in the admin order screen.  It will add your column after the Actions column and populate it with your custom field data.  You'll need to replace my "custom_column" values with your own field names.

```
function wc_add_custom_order_column( $columns ) {

    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_info ) {

        $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;

        if ( 'order_actions' === $column_name ) {
            $new_columns['custom_column'] = __( 'Custom Column', 'my-textdomain' );
        }
    }

    return $new_columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'wc_add_custom_order_column', 20 );

function wc_add_custom_order_column_content( $column ) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'custom_column' === $column ) {
        $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

        if( isset( $data['custom_column'] ) )
            echo $data['custom_column'];
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'wc_add_custom_order_column_content' );
```

Comment: thank you so much, but how can I post to this column's value via WC API?

Comment: Are you trying to access this value from an external system?

Comment: Actually, trying to post this value from my API to WC